# Azure Policy - ARM to exclude Resource Group

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I'm using the following to apply a policy definition. How do I add a Resource Group exclusion to the assignment?

```
{
      "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments",
      "name": "[variables('policyAssignmentAllowedLocations')]",
      "apiVersion": "[variables('deploymentsApiVersion')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/', variables('policyDefinitionAllowedLocations'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "scope": "[subscription().id]",
        "policyDefinitionId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions', variables('policyDefinitionAllowedLocations'))]"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Exclusions can be added to a policy assignment via the `notScopes` property.

The following resource definition describes a policy assignment which excludes a resource group named **excludedResourceGroupName**:

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments",
    "name": "[variables('policyAssignmentAllowedLocations')]",
    "apiVersion": "[variables('deploymentsApiVersion')]",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/', variables('policyDefinitionAllowedLocations'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "scope": "[subscription().id]",
        "policyDefinitionId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions', variables('policyDefinitionAllowedLocations'))]"[resourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions', variables('policyDefinitionAllowedLocations'))]"[resourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions', variables('policyDefinitionAllowedLocations'))]",
        "notScopes" : [
            "[concat(subscription().id,'/resourcegroups/',variables('excludedResourceGroupName'))]"
        ]
    }
}
```